# How do I display file and description field when multiple files are uploaded in a view?

Tags: files

I am using [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to display title and files all together. When I upload multiple files, the description field for each file is enabled, but it is replacing the uploaded filename.

> [image: screenshot]

I want to display both the file and description for each file in the view, not replace the description with the filename.

How can I do this?
sample format image:

[image]

Comment: My original answer didn't account for fields with multiple values so I corrected it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue isn't related directly to `Field collection`, it happens with core `File` fields too.

The tricky part of this question is the "multiple field values". In fields that have multiple values (more than one file allowed to upload into one field) the `delta` counts the file position (0 for first file, 1 for second etc). File descriptions are related to `delta` so the system can know which description is related to which file.

But the problem is working with `delta` in Views, you can't do all sorts of filtering and matching relating to it. For example if you create a View of type `File` you can't seem to match the description of the file (stored in the field database table) with the file (stored in the file database table). You can display either descriptions for all files uploaded to the field a particular file is uploaded to, or limit to only one value, but then you get the same description displayed for all files, which isn't correct.

### The solution

is to create Views of type `Content` (not `File`) because there you can rely on the field option "Multiple field settings" set to **Not** "Display all values in the same row". This means that each file from the field will be displayed in its own individual views row, and file descriptions will match correctly.

Here are the steps to create a list of Files showing both the file name and file description:

- Create a View of type `Content`. Use filters and sorting applicable to your particular case.
- Add a new field `File` from the `Content` category

  - Set the `Formatter` of this field to `Generic file`
  - Make sure that this field **doesn't** have the option "Display all values in the same row" enabled under "Multiple field settings"
  - Under `Rewrite results` enable the option `Override the output of this field with custom text`,
     expand the `Replacement patterns` and copy the code for the file description, it will be something like `{{ field_file__description }}`,
     paste that code into the text area above
     This will give you the file description as text, not linked to anything
- Add a new Relationship `File (field_file:target_id)` (it will be named `file from field_file`)
- Add a new Field `Filename` from the `File` category, it will be automatically set to use the Relationship from the previous step

  - Set its `Formatter` to `File link`. Now you have your linked file.

#### Relationship:

[image: file_Descr_Relationship]

#### Fields:

[image: file_Fields]

#### Views Results:

[image: file_Descr_Results]